# Expected Value: Decimal or Whole values?

Tags: expected-value

Say you are given a sample size consisting of a number of whole objects, such as cats (n=20).

You are asked what the expected value of some factor of these cats is (ex. how many are expected to be blind)

Does a decimal answer make any sense in this regard when the expected value is derived, or should you only consider 'whole' values and disregard any decimal values? Why or why not?

Comment: The decimal value for "the expected value of some factor of these cats is" is acceptable.

Comment: Think about a single die. Each outcome is an integer, but the expected value is 3.5, which is fine. The expected value does not have to be a possible outcome. It's just an average.

Answer (score 1):

Decimal values are acceptable, the expected value do not have to be a possible outcome. Think about *mean number of children per family*.  Look at [mean number of children per family in the USA](https://www.google.no/search?q=mean+number+of+children+per+family+in+usa&oq=mean+number+of+children+per+family+in+usa&aqs=chrome..69i57.12639j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) rounding the means to the closest integer would distort the information content **severely**.

Same answer for cats.

Answer (score 1):

It's decimal. Think of an expected value of the [Bernoulli experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) with probability p. For instance, for a fair coin toss, it's 1/2 despite the whole outcomes 0 and 1.

The best way to think about this seeming contradiction is to consider the expected value as a parameter of the population. For instance, a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) has one parameter, the intensity $\lambda$, which can be any real value. It happens so that the expectation is equal to it: $E[x]=\lambda$, while the outcomes are whole numbers 0,1,2,...